# file() -> DO STUFF -> file_put_contents() sometimes messes up

Tags: php, file-io

I made a visit counter for multiple pages that stores the monthly visits in log.txt files that are formatted as follows: `ID;COUNT`
So whenever someone visits one of the pages the page redirects to a `count.php` where the ID of the page that comes via GET in the URL will be looked up, if it exists in this months log.txt, the program proceeds to add 1 to the value after the semicolon.

So, say, someone visits `page.html`, he gets redirected to `count.php?id=0`, which contains among other stuff, the following lines.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$file = file('./logs/' . $date);
$arr = explode(";",$file[($id)]);
$arr[1] += 1;
$arr = implode(";",$arr) . "\n";
$file[($id)] = $arr;
$fl = implode("",$file);
file_put_contents('./logs/' . $date,$fl);
```

after that, it looks for the ID in another file, where there's the actual target URL for that id, once it has that, the user gets redirected to that.

Most of the time it works as intended, but sometimes it messes up and my logs end up looking like that:

```
;19
;13
;25
;18
;10
;12
;16
;22
;10
;8
100;16
101;28
102;14
```

when it should be looking like that

```
0;13
1;27
2;48
3;990
4;331
.
.
.
101;323
102;392
103;87
104;63
```

One idea that I had was that, because it's quite possible for two people to visit those sites simultaneously, and I didn't implement any file locking, it may get confused with that. But wouldn't that only write old data and not mess with the order or the formatting

Comment: Why read the file each time just to add a line to the end of it. Why not just append the new info to the file and have done with it

Comment: It doesn't add to the `logs.txt`, it looks for the line that contains the ID and adds 1 to the value after the semicolon

Comment: Presumably its doing all this while a user mistakenly think you site is doing something useful for them? You can do all that calculation offline at the end of the month when you want to see these stsistics

Comment: Oh and it more likely to be the processing of the `is this id in the file aleady` that is going wrong that `file_put_contents()` that is making a mistake

Comment: Also I see nowhere where you are testing the existance of or getting and using the `$_GET['id']` in this code

Comment: I am indeed not testing the existance of id, I'm just using it, assuming that if count.php gets called, it must contain an id in the URL, bad practice, I know, but could this really lead to the scrambling of my log files?

Comment: Thats a DEFINITE MAYBE

Comment: There is a security breach called XSS, and you should fix it

Comment: FYI I'm doing the `is this id in the file already` like that: `if(count(array_intersect(logarray,idlistarray)) == count(idlistarray))`

Comment: File locking would be an idea. But of course it will have the potential to slow things down a bit when you do have to users using any page at the same time

Comment: But first you should DEFINITELY check `isset($_GET['id'])` and if its not just bail out as you have to assume its someone messing about, or one of your pages has not got an `?id=` coded correctly. But basically there is nothing you can do but ignore it as quickly as possible